# How to find out the type in internalPointer?

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have model like this(in treeView):

[image]

data1 - one type
hello - second type

data1

```
struct Group
{
 QString name;
 QList<Sample> samples;
}
```

hello

```
struct Sample
{
QString name;
}
```

I have slot

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_clicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    Group *group = static_cast<Group *>(index.internalPointer());
    ui->lineEdit->setText(group->name);
}
```

And i need to know exactly what type of item i choised in internalPointer(Group or Sample). Because the type conversion will always happen, if i used `static_cast<Group *>(index.internalPointer());`

Comment: If you are not planning to add new types, you can use `Group` only, it will be equivalent to `Sample` with an empty list.

Comment: Group and Sample in the real code are very different, and when I perform such a conversion, then all other values are undefined. For example, I have a value for the number of samples in a group. And if I do a type conversion from a sample to a group, then this value is undefined.

Comment: ...or, if the real types are a bit more complicated, have `Group` and `Sample` inherit from a common struct `Base` with a virtual destructor.  That way you can safely(?) cast the internal pointer to `Base *` and use `dynamic_cast` to check which derived type you have.

Comment: If your custom types inherits `QObject`, consider using [qobject_cast](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast), unlike `dynamic_cast` it doesn't require RTTI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using one common base class for all your tree items, as was pointed out in the comments. This base class should declare virtual functions for any piece of data that you'll need in the tree (name, icon, number of children, etc.), which you then override in the derived classes that represent specializations like group and sample. Example:

```
class TreeItem {
public:
    virtual QString GroupName() const {return "";} //Returns an empty string as a default value
    // any other common functions
}

class Group: public TreeItem {
public:
    QString GroupName() const override {return m_name;}
private:
    QString m_name;
}

class Sample: public TreeItem {
    //Let GroupName() default to the base class implementation, or override if necessary
}
```